# Add an item after the specified paragraph, but ignore those that are inside another tag

Tags: php, wordpress, dom

I have code that adds an element to the body of a WordPress post after a certain paragraph.
Unfortunately, I noticed that an element is added to quotes, etc.

My code:

```php
function insert($content, $insertion) {
  $close     = '</p>';
  $parts     = explode($close, $content);
  $paragraph = $insertion['paragraph_number'];

  foreach ($parts as $index => $part) {
    if (trim($part)) {
      $parts[$index] .= $close;
    }

    if (($paragraph == $index + 1)) {
      ob_start(); ?>
      <a href="#"><?= $insertion['content'] ?></a>

<?php $parts[$index] .= ob_get_clean();
    }
  }

  return implode('', $parts);
}
```

Wordpress returns the post with an HTML structure that has no parent, so I guess I can't use a library like this to find a direct paragraph https://github.com/ivopetkov/html5-dom-document-php because child combinator (`>`) requires parent.

Let's say I want to put an element after the third paragraph, it would then look like this:

```html
<p>First paragraph</p>
<p>Second Paragraph</p>
<div>
  <p>Ignore this!</p>
</div>
<p>Third paragraph</p>
<a href="#">Sample insertion</a>
<p>Fifth paragraph</p>
```

How it looks with my current code:

```html
<p>First paragraph</p>
<p>Second Paragraph</p>
<div>
  <p>Ignore this!</p>
  <a href="#">Sample insertion</a>
</div>
<p>Third paragraph</p>
<p>Fifth paragraph</p>
```

This paragraph in the div (or in another tag) shouldn't count.
How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind a div wrapping the paragraph, you can use this `domDocument` method:

It wraps the content in a div first so the content has a parent (this div is removed in the output).

Then it uses xpath to search for the third paragraph that is a direct descendent of the new div wrapper.

It will also create a new version of the third paragraph with another wrapper so that it has a parent, then it appends the link as a child of that wrapper.

```
    $str = "
    <p>First paragraph</p>
<p>Second Paragraph</p>
<div>
  <p>Ignore this!</p>
</div>
<p>Third paragraph</p>
<p>Fifth paragraph</p>
    ";
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    @$dom->loadHTML("<div class='pwrap'>$str</div>", LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
    
    $new = $dom->createElement("a");
    $new->setAttribute("href","#");
    $new->nodeValue = "ADDED";
    
    $xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $tag = $xPath->query("//div[@class='pwrap']/p[position()=3]")[0];

    $p = $dom->createElement("p");
    $p->nodeValue = $tag->nodeValue;
    
    $newP = $dom->createElement("div");
    $newP->setAttribute("class","linkwrap");
    $newP->appendChild($p);
    $newP->appendChild($new);
    $newP->removeAttribute("class");
    $tag->parentNode->replaceChild($newP, $tag);
    
    $output = trim($dom->saveHTML());
    $output = trim(substr($output,19,strlen($output)-25));
    echo $output;
```